# Maven deployment timeout / failure to generate checksums

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, deployment, maven-deploy-plugin

I'm trying to deploy an artifact to [clojars](https://clojars.org/) which provides a public Maven repository.

When I run the deployment I get a failure at the end with the following output, apparently after a 60 secs timeout:

```
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ clisk ---
Uploading: https://clojars.org/repo/net/mikera/clisk/0.3.0/clisk-0.3.0.jar
Uploading: https://clojars.org/repo/net/mikera/clisk/0.3.0/clisk-0.3.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2:13.466s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Aug 07 08:51:00 SGT 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/253M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project clisk: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact net.mikera:clisk:jar:0.3.0 from/to clojars (https://clojars.org/repo): No response received after 60000 -> [Help 1]
```

Interestingly, the following happens:

- The jar and the pom *are* successfully deployed (I can see them in the repo)
- The various MD5 / SHA1 checksums *are not* generated

Further links:

- The [reported issue](https://github.com/mikera/clisk/issues/2)
- The [pom.xml](https://github.com/mikera/clisk/blob/0.3.0/pom.xml)

I'm using the built-in Maven support within Eclipse Juno

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a complete solution but a workaround I found, posted here in case anyone else needs it.

- Build the code and install in the local repository with "Run As.../Maven Install"
- Make sure `pageant` is running with your SSH key (from the PuTTY suite). The SSH key must match the public key you provide to Clojars in your profile
- Open a console and cd into the ".m2" local repository directory to find you .pom and .jar files
- Run the following command:

  pscp -scp *.pom *.jar clojars@clojars.org:

This seems to work successfully: Clojars itself will generate the required checksum files.